# Getting BigQuery SP result into SSRS report

Tags: mysql, google-bigquery, reporting-services

Looking for a solution to load BQ Stored Procedure result as a source of SSRS report.
In SSRS dataset, I have tried to use 'Call My_SP()' in query and it will return this error:
Query execution failed for dataset 'DataSet1'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand)
ERROR [HY000] [Simba][BigQuery] (100) Error interacting with REST API: Not found: Job [project_id]:[job_id].
However, if I write the script directly into the query box it will return the list I want.

My guess is the SSRS cannot get correct temp table id which stores the SP result but I am not sure with it. If this is the root cause, does anyone have any idea on how to solve this issue?Or does anyone have any idea on what is the best practice on loading BQ SP result into SSRS?